# Page numbering component, map array to find path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a page number component using an array of objects, containing a path and id.

```
import React from 'react';

export function PageNumber(props) {

const pageData = [
{path: '/calc/1', id:1},
{path: '/calc/2', id:2},
{path: '/calc/3', id:3},
{path: '/calc/4', id:4},
{path: '/calc/5', id:5},
{path: '/calc/6', id:6},
{path: '/calc/7', id:7}
]

const CurrentPage = props.location.pathname;
const numberOfPages = pageData.length;
```

How can I map my array and only show the current page?

```
  return (
      <div>{        
            pageData.map(page => {
                page.path == CurrentPage ? page.path : ''

                <span>{page.path} of {numberOfPages}</span>
            })}  
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are mapping your array and return a component, aren't you? I don't understand your question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping may not be needed in your case. Try this :

```
const CurrentPage = props.location.pathname || pageData[0] ;
return (
  <span>{CurrentPage.path} of {pageData.length}</span> 
);
```